# Do all $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-comonoids in $\mathcal{C}_*$ come from “freely-pointed” $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-comonoids on $\mathcal{C}$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra

In [*Coalgebras in symmetric monoidal categories of spectra*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02592), Péroux and Shipley prove the following ([Lemma 2.4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02592.pdf#defi.2.4)):

> Let $\mathcal{C}=\mathsf{Sets},\mathsf{Top}$, or $\mathsf{sSets}$. The free basepoint functor
> $$(-)^+\colon(\mathcal{C},\times,\mathrm{pt})\to(\mathcal{C}_*,\wedge,S^0)$$
> lifts to an equivalence of categories
> $$(-)^+\colon\mathsf{CoMon}(\mathcal{C})\dashrightarrow\mathsf{CoMon}(\mathcal{C}_*).$$
> As such, any comonoid in $\mathcal{C}_*$ is isomorphic to one of the form $(C^+,\Delta^+_{C},\epsilon^+_C)$ with $(C,\Delta_{C},\epsilon_C)$ a comonoid in $\mathcal{C}$.

- Is this result valid in general for $\mathcal{C}$ a bicomplete Cartesian closed symmetric monoidal category, where $(\mathcal{C}_*,\wedge,S^0)$ is now the symmetric monoidal category in [Riehl, *Categorical Homotopy Theory*, Construction 3.3.14](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/cathtpy.pdf#thm.3.3.14)?
- Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a bicomplete Cartesian closed symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category.

  1. Can we similarly build a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category structure  $(\wedge,S^0)$ on the category $\mathcal{C}_*$ of pointed objects of $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e. the coslice $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}_{*/}$)?
  2. If this is the case, do we have an analogue of Péroux–Shipley's result for $\mathbb{E}_{k}$-comonoids in $(\mathcal{C}_*,\wedge,S^0)$, where $1\leq k\leq\infty$?
  3. (If Item 1 fails, is Item 2 nevertheless true for $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{S}$, the $\infty$-category of spaces?)

Comment: I am confused by your reference to my comment. I was talking about $E_k$-monoids, and here you seem to be talking about $E_k$-comonoids...

Comment: @DenisNardin sorry, I completely misunderstood your comment (and have reverted the edit back). Thanks!

Comment: An update: Maximilien replied to my question in email: 1) Lemma 2.4 is valid for all $(\mathcal{C}_*,\wedge,S^0)$; 2) One can carry this construction over to the $\infty$-setting too; 3) The analogue of his result with Shipley is true for $\mathcal{S}_*$, and in fact also for any $\infty$-topos.