# Variations on Thomason's equivalence between connective spectra and symmetric monoidal categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, monoidal-categories, ring-spectra

There's a number of results relating monoidal categories to connective spectra (which are themselves equivalent to $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-spaces):

- [*Symmetric monoidal categories model all connective spectra*](https://www.emis.de/journals/TAC/volumes/1995/n5/v1n5.pdf);
- In [Modelling Connective Spectra via Multicategories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.11148), Fuentes-Keuthan proves the statement in the title, and also refines in Theorem 5.3 Thomason's result, showing that symmetric monoidal *groupoids* suffice to model all connective spectra;
- In [*Modeling Stable One-Types*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2686), Johnson–Osorno showed that Picard categories model $1$-truncated spectra;
- In [*Stable homotopy hypothesis in the Tamsamani model*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05577), Moser–Ozornova–Paoli–Sarazola–Verdugo proved that symmetric monoidal weak $n$-groupoids model $n$-truncated spectra.

Are the following three variants on these results true?

- Do [symmetric monoidal categories with zero](https://mathoverflow.net/a/402524) model all $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-spaces with zero?
- Do (braided, symmetric) semiring categories model all connective ($\mathbb{E}_{2}$-, $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-)ring spaces?
- Do (braided, symmetric) *ring* categories model all connective *$1$-truncated* ($\mathbb{E}_{2}$-, $\mathbb{E}_{\infty}$-)ring spectra? (Related: see [*Modeling Stable One-Types*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2686), Remark 3.2).